# Many to many query with filter

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have following issue. There are two tables - `groups` and `students` and third pivot table `group_student`.

Query to get students from specific groups (id:1,8) is clear...

```
   SELECT DISTINCT s.*
   FROM students AS s
   Inner Join group_student AS gs ON gs.student_id = s.id
   Inner Join groups AS g ON g.id = gs.group_id
   WHERE g.id IN ("1","8")
```

It works. But, how to query, if I want to select just segment of students of group id 1. For example `s.name = "john"`. So the result should be: `all students from group id 8 + all students with name "john" from group id 1`.

Thanx for posts :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
   FROM students AS s
   Inner Join group_student AS gs ON gs.student_id = s.id
   Inner Join groups AS g ON g.id = gs.group_id
   WHERE g.id ="8" or (g.id="1" and s.name = "john")
```

Comment: it will select one data set at one time, not both

Answer (score 1):

you can use UNION too

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
   FROM students AS s
   Inner Join group_student AS gs ON gs.student_id = s.id
   Inner Join groups AS g ON g.id = gs.group_id
   WHERE g.id = 8
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
   FROM students AS s
   Inner Join group_student AS gs ON gs.student_id = s.id
   Inner Join groups AS g ON g.id = gs.group_id
   WHERE gp.id="1" and s.name = "john"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option, avoiding `DISTINCT` and the (probably unneeded) join to `groups`:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM students AS s
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM group_student AS gs 
          WHERE gs.student_id = s.id
            AND (  gs.group_id = 8
                OR (gs.group_id, s.name) = (1, 'john')
                )
        )
```